# why does this output returns different value every time?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def solution(dict, output, ini):
    if (dict == None):
        return None
    else:
        for key in dict:
            if str(type(dict[key])) != str(type({})):
                print(key)
                output[ini + key] = dict[key]
            else:
                return solution(dict[key], output, ini + key + '.')
    return output

a = {
    'Key1': '1',
    'Key2': {
        'a': '2',
        'b': '3',
        'c': {
            'd': '3',
            'e': '1'
        }
    }
}
print(solution(a, {}, ""))
```

Hello I am trying to make a function that flattens nested dictionary.

For example a should print:

```
{'Key2.b': '3', 'Key1': '1', 'Key2.c.d': '3', 'Key2.a': '2', 'Key2.c.e': '1'}
```

But right now the code randomly gives me back the correct answer but from a range of 0-5 such as

```
{'Key2.b': '3', 'Key1': '1', 'Key2.c.d': '3', 'Key2.a': '2'},
{'Key2.b': '3', 'Key2.c.d': '3'}
```

I found out that if i get rid of the "return" in my else statement it would work but i am not sure why that is? Can anybody help me with it

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over the keys in `dict` with `for key in dict:` it will return the keys in random order since elements in dictionaries aren't ordered. If `Key1` is processed first it will be added to output and on the next iteration `Key2` will be recursively processed. Now if the order is different and `Key2` is processed first then `return solution(dict[key],output,ini+key+'.')` will cause the result to be returned before `Key1` gets added to output. Same goes with nested elements within `Key2`. If you remove the `return` statement then all the keys will be processed no matter the iteration order and you'll get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

as you put the result in `output`, you should not `return` at `else`,otherwise, the `for` loop will break, and the rest keys will be ignored.（just remove `return`, and it will do work）